# this pointer and QSharedPointer

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, shared-ptr, qsharedpointer

I have a tree-node like class called `Message` which looks like this:

```
class Message
{
public:
    using Ptr = QSharedPointer<Message>;

public:
    explicit Message();
    explicit Message(Message::Ptr parentPtr);
    explicit Message(const Data &data, Message::Ptr parentPtr = Message::Ptr());

    void setParent(Message::Ptr parentPtr);
    Message::Ptr parent() const;
    bool hasParent() const;

    QSet<Message::Ptr> children() const;
    void setChildren(const QSet<Message::Ptr> &children);
    bool hasChildren() const;

    Data data() const;
    void setData(const Data &data);

private:
    void addChild(Message::Ptr childPtr);
    void removeChild(Message::Ptr childPtr);

private:
    Message::Ptr m_parentPtr;
    QSet<Message::Ptr> m_children;
    Data m_data;
};
```

This class can have a parent and a set of children. I have a problem when I implemented the `addChild` and `setParent` member functions:

```
void Message::addChild(Message::Ptr childPtr)
{
    if (!m_children.contains(childPtr)) {
        m_children.insert(childPtr);
    }

    Message::Ptr thisPtr(this);

    if (childPtr->parent() != thisPtr) {
        childPtr->setParent(thisPtr);
    }
}

void Message::setParent(Message::Ptr parentPtr)
{
    if (m_parentPtr != parentPtr) {
        m_parentPtr = parentPtr;

        m_parentPtr->addChild(Message::Ptr(this));
    }
}
```

**What I expect will happen:**

1. `Message::addChild` gets called
2. `thisPtr` gets created with a reference count of 1
3. `childPtr->parent() != thisPtr` will be resolved to `true`
4. `childPtr->setParent(thisPtr);`, `Message::setParent` gets executed and `thisPtr` reference count will increase by 1 as a copy of the shared pointer is created. Now `thisPtr` has a reference count of 2
5. As `Message::setParent` gets executed, `m_parentPtr = parentPtr;` will increase `m_parentPtr`, `parentPtr` and thus `thisPtr` reference counts by 1; these 3 smart pointers now have a reference count of 3.
6. Execution exits `Message::setParent` and destroy `parentPtr` decreasing the reference count of `m_parentPtr` and `thisPtr` by 1
7. Execution returns to `Message::addChild`. Now reference count of `thisPtr` is 2.

**What actually happens:**

When execution exits the `if` statement in `Message::addChild` `thisPtr` reference count decreases again by 1, leaving `thisPtr` with a reference count of 1. This makes everything break as when execution exists `Message::addChild`, `thisPtr` gets destroyed, thus `this` deleted.

**My question:**

Why does `thisPtr` reference count decreases again by when execution exits the `if` statement in `Message::addChild` or what actually happens there?...

Here is how it runs in the debugger:
[image]

Comment: You can't just hand over ownership of `*this` to a `QSharedPointer` (you're even doing it multiple times). Read [the documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsharedpointer.html#QSharedPointer-1).

Comment: Wow, that's an annoying animation - couldn't you have put that into text form?

Comment: @JesperJuhl Well that's exactly what I did on those 7 points at *What I expect will happen*...

Comment: @molbdnilo Yes, you're right!

Comment: Ohh, I forgot to say "and then ditch that annoying annimation' ;-) but maybe that's just me..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 5. As `Message::setParent` gets executed, `m_parentPtr = parentPtr;` will increase `m_parentPtr`, `parentPtr` and thus `thisPtr` reference counts by 1; these 3 smart pointers now have a reference count of 3.

5.1. Then, `setParent` constructs a temporary shared pointer to the child **with reference count 1** and calls `addChild` on the parent:

```
m_parentPtr->addChild(Message::Ptr(this));
```

5.2. `addChild` creates a shared pointer to the parent **with reference count 1**:

```
Message::Ptr thisPtr(this);
```

5.3. `addChild` returns, destroying that shared pointer of 5.2, which destroys the parent, which destroys the parent's `QSet<Message::Ptr> m_children` member.

5.4. The temporary shared pointer of 5.1 is destroyed, which destroys the child.

More generally, you have a cyclic reference: parents own children, and children own their parents, which is a recipe for memory leaks and use-after-delete bugs. Constructing new shared pointers owning raw pointers already owned by other shared pointers is a recipe for double-delete and use-after-delete bugs; the shared pointers won't know about each other, their reference counts will vary independently. You should investigate [`QWeakPointer`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qweakpointer.html) to break the cycle and [`QEnableSharedFromThis`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qenablesharedfromthis.html) to safely obtain a shared pointer to `*this`.